# is there a way I could set the input of the pieces for chess to the index of the grid(2D array)?

Tags: java, arrays, input

So before i move on forward adjust the program I'm doing for chess, I don't think using string and putting it in the grid will be a good idea, so that if later on i want to compare the position of the current piece to another and so on it would be so difficult to do that, so is there a way where instead of me doing, Rook = sc.nextLine(); or anything piece and maybe something like this,

edit1:if i try to compare or use the string inputs to the grid, wont work since its Grid is a 2D array string, so I want to get all of the inputs as a 2D array, how would i do that? is that clear? Sorry about my english - thats my problem

```
// private String[][] Rook;
// something here i don't know how to do and set it to the grid index 
// Rook[grid] = sc.nextline(), this wont work I know because im using a int into a Rook String[][] . so is there a way to do Rook 2D array and set it to the array grid?
```

.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    class chessMoves
    {
      //MAIN CODE AT THE VERY BOTTOM OF THE CLASS
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

      private String[][] grid = new String[8][8];
      //target is x, so if x is at location in the grid, your program should determine if
      // any of the pieces can move to that position.
      private String king,queen,rook,bishop,knight,target;

      public void chessPieces(){

        //remember you're only using the peices in scanner for a string just for a test
        //switch them to 2D Array so that i can access it easilyaas








        System.out.println("Hello Guest00129, Welcome to Chess.");
        System.out.println("In order to play this game, input pieces like below(cap;atilaized)");
        System.out.println("Rook at column c and at row 5 then: Rc5");







        System.out.println("Please enter a position for Rook");
        rook = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a position for King");
        king = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a position for Queen");
        queen = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a position for Bishop");
        bishop = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a position for Knight");
        knight = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter a position for Target(X) to move the peices to that position");
        target = sc.nextLine();


      }

      public void printGrid(){






        for(int row = 0; row <grid.length; row++){
          for (int column = 0;column <grid[row].length; column++){
            grid[row][column] = ".";
          }
        }    
        grid[7-rook.charAt(2)+49][(int)rook.charAt(1)-97] = "R";
        grid[7-bishop.charAt(2)+49][(int)bishop.charAt(1)-97] = "B";
        grid[7-queen.charAt(2)+49][(int)queen.charAt(1)-97] = "Q";
        grid[7-king.charAt(2)+49][(int)king.charAt(1)-97] = "K";
        grid[7-knight.charAt(2)+49][(int)knight.charAt(1)-97] = "I";
        grid[7-target.charAt(2)+49][(int)target.charAt(1)-97] = "X";


        for(int row = 0; row <grid.length; row++){
          for (int column = 0;column <grid[row].length; column++){
            System.out.printf("%2s",grid[row][column] + " ");
          }
          System.out.println();
        }


      }

      //get the userinput working first then make a file that gets the information for that userinput and outputs here
      public void readChessPositions(){

      }



      //the file created from the method above read it print the grid here like printout here and show the possible
      //positons that can attack 
      public void chessOutput(){


      }

      //method that prints the grid with the positiosn showed in the outputfile of chess moves
      //print all empty spaces with dot(.) and the postiions
      public static void main (String[] args){


        chessMoves test1 = new chessMoves();
        test1.chessPieces();
        test1.printGrid();



      }


    }
```

Comment: What is the actual question/problem?

Comment: if i try to compare or use the string inputs to the grid, wont work since its Grid is a 2D array string, so I want to get all of the inputs as a 2D array, how would i do that? is that clear? Sorry about my english

Comment: instead of Rook = sc.nextLine();
can i do something like 

Rook[some Value equal to grid][samething] = sc.Nextline(); ?

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question as you literally wrote it:

> instead of Rook = sc.nextLine(); can i do something like Rook[some Value equal to grid][samething] = sc.Nextline(); ?

You cannot, because Rook is not a defined type, nor is it a 2d array, nor can it be defined as a String.

I believe what you're trying to ask though, is how you might represent a chess position outside of a "Strings and grids" approach, which is entirely possible with a more Object Oriented approach, and I've quickly thrown together a rough example that uses no 2D arrays whatsoever:

Consider the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class ChessPiece {
    private Point position;
    private String myteam;  // Black or White.

    public Point getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    //...presumably a setPosition method exists, 
    //as well as an abstract move validator. 
}
```

You can then extend this class for each of your chess piece classes: `Pawn`, `Rook`, `Bishop`, `Knight`, `Queen`, `King`, adding piece specific logic as necessary.  Since we know that Chess takes place on an 8x8 grid, we must validate at all times that Point.x and Point.y are within the range of 0-7, inclusive, and doesn't collide with other pieces.  Comparing piece positions is merely a matter of comparing their Point members.

The overall game state may simply contain a Collection of all of the piece objects, giving a functional (in-memory) representation of a board without a grid in sight.

There is of course a multitude of other options for representing your chess game, though, and they are probably better than what I just whipped together.  A Google session indicates that [bitboards](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Bitboards) are a popular and solid approach to chess representations.

Comment: Thanks, but so you're saying there is no need for 2D array? because my task required to have a grid 8 by 8 and output "." for empty spaces and the rest output the pieces from user input. so I was just wondering if those pieces from the user input could be done using 2D.

Comment: Since all you're storing is where pieces are, all your draw really has to do is for each possible position check if a piece is there, and draw the piece.  You can draw empty spaces by default without needing to store the entire grid.  I do not know what you mean by 'input could be done using 2D'; are you meaning point and click input?

Comment: K what i was trying to say if I choose the Queen at position, Qb2, in other words Queen at column 2, at row 2, how can i get the index of that from the grid ? like do i do Grid[queen.charAt("Q")] in order to get the coordinates for that position ?

Comment: Umm...are you inputting that the Queen is at row 2 column 2?  Because then you have the coordinates already by virtue of having just typed them in.  Otherwise, the `Queen.getPosition()` method in my proposed model will return the coordinates stored in the Queen's Point object.  `charAt(...)` would never be applicable, as it's meant to show a character at a given position, rather than search for a character's position.